# JTable showing and updating line numbers in View

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a 'JTable' added to the 'JScroll' Pane. I want to display line numbers for each row in the 'JTable' without changing the 'JTable' model.

The below link is a nice solution which solves my line number issue. 
[LineNumber Solution](http://www.javarichclient.com/display-line-numbers-jtable/)
However the line number column gets added till the entire scroll Pane height. Even though the JTable has no rows, or just 1 row, this extra blank gray column shows up for the entire height of the scroll Pane. I tried changing the ScrollPane height, table height everything.. Nothing seems to make the line number column as high as just the current table rows.

Can you please suggest a away to have this Line Number column height according to table rows and increase/decrease height according to new rows being added or deleted?

Comment: Modify the code to listen to how many items are in the Table and then only draw that many gray line areas? Would that be possible?

Comment: @NESPowerGlove Yes, I tried to get the row numbers from the model. And then setting the height to that dimension. But its somehow not working. I got the height by using the below: Rectangle tblRect = table.getCellRect(table.getModel().getRowCount()-1, 0, false); //Getting table dimensions

Comment: Well I didn't look too much at the code on that website, but I'd imagine it was looping through from 1 to n to create those line numbers, so isn't there somewhere to stop the looping not at n, but at number of items in the table?

Comment: It does loop through the table.getRowCount() number of items, to add proper line line numbers. And the problem is not with the line numbers as they are generated only until the number of table rows as expected. But the problem is that the lineNumber column (just the blank column) gets added even if the table has 0 rows. And the line number column is added for the entire height of the JScrollPane which looks very bad. (I would post a screen shot if I had higher reputation.) I want to paint the line Number Column only till table height and not for the entire ViewPort size.

Answer (score 1):

The [Row Number Table](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/) bases the row header on the number of rows in the JTable (most current version will be found at this link).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

/*
 *  Use a JTable as a renderer for row numbers of a given main table.
 *  This table must be added to the row header of the scrollpane that
 *  contains the main table.
 */
public class RowNumberTable extends JTable
    implements ChangeListener, PropertyChangeListener
{
    private JTable main;

    public RowNumberTable(JTable table)
    {
        main = table;
        main.addPropertyChangeListener( this );
        main.getModel().addTableModelListener( this );

        setFocusable( false );
        setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel( false );
        setSelectionModel( main.getSelectionModel() );
        setRowHeight( main.getRowHeight() );

        TableColumn column = new TableColumn();
        column.setHeaderValue(" ");
        addColumn( column );
        column.setCellRenderer(new RowNumberRenderer());

        getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
        setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(getPreferredSize());
    }

    @Override
    public void addNotify()
    {
        super.addNotify();

        Component c = getParent();

        //  Keep scrolling of the row table in sync with the main table.

        if (c instanceof JViewport)
        {
            JViewport viewport = (JViewport)c;
            viewport.addChangeListener( this );
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Delegate method to main table
     */
    @Override
    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return main.getRowCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowHeight(int row)
    {
        int rowHeight = super.getRowHeight(row);
        int mainRowHeight = main.getRowHeight(row);

        if (rowHeight != mainRowHeight)
        {
            super.setRowHeight(row, mainRowHeight);
        }

        return mainRowHeight;
    }

    /*
     *  No model is being used for this table so just use the row number
     *  as the value of the cell.
     */
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column)
    {
        return Integer.toString(row + 1);
    }

    /*
     *  Don't edit data in the main TableModel by mistake
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /*
     *  Do nothing since the table ignores the model
     */
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {}
//
//  Implement the ChangeListener
//
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
    {
        //  Keep the scrolling of the row table in sync with main table

        JViewport viewport = (JViewport) e.getSource();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane)viewport.getParent();
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(viewport.getViewPosition().y);
    }
//
//  Implement the PropertyChangeListener
//
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
    {
        //  Keep the row table in sync with the main table

        if ("selectionModel".equals(e.getPropertyName()))
        {
            setSelectionModel( main.getSelectionModel() );
        }

        if ("rowHeight".equals(e.getPropertyName()))
        {
            repaint();
        }

        if ("model".equals(e.getPropertyName()))
        {
            main.getModel().addTableModelListener( this );
            revalidate();
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Attempt to mimic the table header renderer
     */
    private static class RowNumberRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
    {
        public RowNumberRenderer()
        {
            setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
        {
            if (table != null)
            {
                JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();

                if (header != null)
                {
                    setForeground(header.getForeground());
                    setBackground(header.getBackground());
                    setFont(header.getFont());
                }
            }

            if (isSelected)
            {
                setFont( getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD) );
            }

            setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
            setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));

            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this class. However there is some issue as it does not generate or update row numbers after row 2.

Comment: The source code for row number table gives my browser a whole bunch of security warnings when trying to download. Do you have it hosted somewhere else?

Comment: I have been thinking about moving the code to github. But I haven't done that yet, so this is the only place.

Comment: @camickr All good, thanks for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. Posting the fix incase someone else will benefit in future.

I had to first paint the lineNumber column white for the entire height of scrollPane. Then I got the last row of the table and its rectangle position and painted the lineNumber column with the background color only till the height of the rectangle. Below is the extra code I added to the LineNumberTableRowHeader class.

```
        Rectangle tblRect = table.getCellRect(table.getModel().getRowCount()-1, 0, false); //Getting table dimensions
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    g.setColor(getBackground());
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), tblRect.height+ tblRect.y);
```